# Call piece of c++ code once in multiprocess environment

Tags: linux, c++11, posix, mutex, semaphore

I am currently developing some piece of code which should execute once in multiprocess environment.

```
//foo.cpp --> Shared library linked by both process1 and process2
void foo() { std::cout << "foo : Makesure I call only once in multiprocess environment \n"; }

//process1.cpp
int main() { foo(); }

//process2.cpp
int main() { foo(); }
```

I need to call foo() function only once either by process1/process2 in C++ environment.

Only Alternative solution I can think off is to creating dummy_file inside foo at firsttime and print message, If file already exist should not print message.

any suggestion would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Only Alternative solution I can think of is to creating dummy_file inside foo at firsttime and print message, If file already exist should not print message.

Yes. This is a viable alternative. If you were on Windows I'd say it would be better to have a Registry entry instead so the file can't easily/accidentally be deleted, but I see you've tagged the question for linux.

[See this article on IPC for Linux](https://opensource.com/article/19/4/interprocess-communication-linux-storage) for other solutions than using a file.